# Compute the Eigenvectors & Show A is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

$A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1&2&1 \\
        0&1&0 \\
        1&3&1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

I computed the eigenvalues:

$λ_ 1 = 1$

$λ_ 2 = 0$

$λ_ 3 = 2$

The corresponding eigenvalues I computed are:

$X_{λ1} =         
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        (-1/2) x_3  \\
        x_3 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$ Substitute $x_1$ as 1, $x_3$ as 2: $X_{λ1} =         
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x1 \\
        -1  \\
        2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$

$X_{λ2} =         
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -x_3 \\
        0  \\
        x_3 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$ Substitute $x_3$ as 1: $X_{λ2} =         
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        0  \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$

$X_{λ3} =         
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x_3 \\
        0  \\
        x_3 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$ Substitute $x_3$ as 1: $X_{λ3} =         
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0  \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$

To show A is diagonalizable:

$S =         
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1&-1&1 \\
        -1&0&0  \\
        2&1&1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$

$S^{-1}AS = D$

AS = SD

After matrix multiplication, I got

$       
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1&0&2 \\
        -1&0&0  \\
        0&0&2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$ = $       
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1&0&2 \\
        -1&0&0  \\
        2&0&2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$

I know I made a mistake somewhere because AS does not equal SD. I can't find my mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you get for $X_{λ1}$?  It should be $\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Double check your basis vector for your first eigenspace

Comment: I see my mistake. I accidentally wrote a 0 instead of a 1 in the $a_{31}$ spot while finding my first eigenvector. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to remove this question from the "Unanswered" queue, it's clear from the comments that Christina's problem has been solved.